# Using current url in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, url

I have this js function

```
function twitterShare(){
    window.open( 'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+$(".section-title h1").text() +'         
    '+window.location, "twitterWindow",
    "height=380,width=660,resizable=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,status=0,location=0,scrollbars=0") 
    return false;
}
```

When the twitter window opens it grabs the .section-title h1 class, but I need it to say something like this,

"Check this out here: http://currentwebsiteurl.com"

I need a text string then grab the url of the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "it"? Which it? twitter? the new page?

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that but couldn't figure out how to write the function the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location.href` contains the current URL of the page.

So your function should look like this:

```
function twitterShare(){
    window.open('http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check this out here: ' + window.location.href,
                "twitterWindow", "height=380,width=660,resizable=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,status=0,location=0,scrollbars=0")
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href`. It holds the value of the current page you are on.